# Django delete error when foreignKey on_delete=CASCADE

Tags: django

I see the following errors occasionally and don't understand why.

> query DELETE FROM "cart_cart" WHERE "cart_cart"."id" IN (211244)
> 23:13:27 exception ForeignKeyViolation: update or delete on table
> "cart_cart" violates foreign key constraint
>
> "cart_cartline_cart_id_c7b9981e_fk_cart_cart_id" on table
> "cart_cartline" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(211244) is still referenced from
> table "cart_cartline".

When my cart_cartline table definition has the following line..

```
 class CartLine(ItemLine):

     cart = models.ForeignKey(
         "Cart", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
         related_name='cart_line_set',
     )
```

Shouldn't django just delete the cart and the related cart lines?

Comment: It should. What does `ItemLine` class look like? Also did you makemigrations & migrate if you made any changes to your model?

Comment: Have same issue. Didn't  you find solution?

Comment: @PaulShishmarev no I didn't , I am just ignoring the error atm :(